# Title to the graph when saved as image in Echarts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, graph, echarts

I want to give title to the **graph image** which we get when we save the graph as image in **Echarts**. **Echarts** does not have option for the same. So, is there any way that we can achieve our requirement.

Attaching a link for your reference from echarts. Which provide the option for **saveAsImage**
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.saveAsImage

As attaching a link of  echarts example which has **save image icon** on the right top corner

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=area-rainfall

I also want to position the hover tooltip which we get on hover of the save image icon. they have some default options. But, I have to increase the space more.

I really thank the guys who can come up with the solution for the above requirement.

Answer (score 4):

**By default, the name of the image is the chart title.**

You can set the title by using:

```
option: {
    title: {
        text: 'myTitle'
    }
}
```

To provide a custom name, you can use the [`saveAsImage.name`](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.saveAsImage.name) function:

```
option: {
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {
                name: 'myImageName'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Bonus: To increase the space between the icons, you can set [`toolbox.itemGap`](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.itemGap), and maybe get the result you want:

```
option: {
    toolbox: {
        itemGap: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        ...
    }
}
```

Or customize the icons itself through [`toolbox.iconStyle`](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.iconStyle). For example, by setting a transparent border:

```
option: {
    toolbox: {
        iconStyle: {
            borderWidth: 10,
            borderColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Toolbox documentation](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox)

Answer (score 0):

```js
option: {
        toolbox: {
            feature: {
                saveAsImage: {
                    title: 'Save',
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.